# Total derivative of function at 0

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> what is the total derivative at 0 of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^p \to\mathbb{R}^q$ that satisfies $\|f(x)\| \leq \|x\|^2$.

I am a bit unsure of my method.

By the chain rule we have $$ f'(x)/\|f\| \leq 2x $$. After this I am a bit lost. Any hints or pointers ? Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that we are working in $\mathbb{R}^p$ where $p$ could be greater than $1$, so what you wrote doesn't make sense, since there's no order on $\mathbb{R}^p$ if $p>1$. As for your question, here's a hint: if $A$ is the zero matrix, i.e. $A$ is a $q$ by $p$ matrix with all entries zero, then what is $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac{\|f(x)-Ax\|}{\|x\|}}$?

Comment: @JoeyZou Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition implies that $f(0)=0$ and that $\|f(\mathbf x)\|=o(\|\mathbf x\|^2)$. So, $f(0+\mathbf h)=f(0)+\operatorname{d}f_0[\mathbf h]+o(\mathbf h)$, which, after substituting and rearranging, gives $\operatorname{d}f_0[\mathbf h]=o(\mathbf h)$. What does this say about the *linear* operator $\operatorname{d}f_0$?

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful.

Comment: @img_teacher It’s essentially what Joey Zou was hinting at, but stated in a different way.

Comment: Oh yes. Both of your suggestions were helpful. Just that I was not near a PC, but rather on a mobile device. Which is rather annoying to type on. Anyway, thank you for your help. Happy new year!